# what would be the best way to migration data from SQL Azure to Azure Table

Tags: azure, migration, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

For a project, I am using both SQL Azure and Azure table. A requirement here is that for the first 7 days, all data are stored in SQL Azure. After the first 7 days, the data are migrated into Azure table.

Is there any reliable project to achieve this goal? Or any idea to implement this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool to do so, take a look at Cloud Storage Studio (http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloudstoragestudio) which has a feature to import data from SQL Server to Azure Table Storage. I haven't checked for a long time but I believe ClumsyLeaf's TableXplorer (http://www.clumsyleaf.com) also has this feature. Long time back, we also built an open source tool to do the same. You can find it here: http://azuredatabaseupload.codeplex.com/.

As David mentioned, you could basically write some views in your database to fetch data older than 7 days. The idea is simple: You fetch the data, map the SQL Server data types to Azure data types, choose appropriate PartitionKey/RowKey values, convert the data into entities and then upload entities in batches.

Comment: Good point on Cloud Storage Studio. The only reason I didn't suggest desktop-style tools: I figured this needed to run in an automated fashion, within the role instances, which would mean Cloud Storage Studio would need to be installed at role startup. Curious: Does it also have any type of command-line automation options? (if not: feel free to add it, so I can tell people I came up with that idea!).

Comment: David, currently it does not have the "invoke from command line" feature. However we built this feature in CSS on top of the one on CodePlex which is open source. One can take the code from there and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best best is to have a set of SQL queries (or sprocs) that return data older than 7 days. Then have table-insertion code that writes this data to one or more tables, with appropriate partition/row key based on your query needs. Then, just build some type of background operation to perform the read+write+delete. There's no tool to do this (that I know of), since one is a relational database and the other is a NoSQL variant with no specific schema.

To optimize your writes, see if you can write batches of rows at the same time (this is called an Entity Group Transaction). It optimizes # of transactions, plus the rows in a group will be written atomically. See more info on entity group transactions, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx).

You also may want to consider using a queue for workload assignment. That is, maybe once a day (or hour, whenever), push a queue message telling some background process to transfer data from SQL to Table Storage. This way, in case something fails during the operation, you can process it again later, since the queue message will still be there (you'd only delete the message if the operation succeeded).